# PHP Query Script - Check empty variable before querying

Tags: php, database

I have php script which receives many variables from JavaScript search form. The thing is some of these variable could be empty so I have to check each one before querying it. e.g: user could enter the name and id of student and leave the gender field empty, so how I supposed to write the query? I've read that I might need use append but I have no idea how to do that. Any other better idea ?

**piece of script:**

```
$name = ($_GET['name']); 
$id = ($_GET['id']);
$gender = ($_GET['gender']);

 (!$con) {
    throw new Exception("Error in connection to DB");
     }

   $query ="SELECT grade FROM students  WHERE name ILIKE '%$name%' ";
   $result = pg_query($query);
```

**EDIT**

Okay if I use empty and isset functions, then I have to check every variable and write new query? How can I update the original query after checking ?

Comment: look at empty and isset functions

Answer (score 2):

With PHP you can use `empty` and `isset` as such:

```
if (!isset($_GET['name']) || empty($_GET['name'])) {
  // Error detection, this field isn't available
}
```

Please note that `isset` is actually redundant in this example, as `empty` will return false if it is not set.

Documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0):

**empty ( )**

Determine whether a variable is empty :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

**isset ( )**

Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the variable content like this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['name'])) {
    // make your query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think outside the box.

```
<?php
$first = TRUE;
$var_names = array('name', 'age', 'gender');

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE"

foreach( $_GET as $key => $value ) {
    if( in_array($key, $var_names) && !empty($_GET[$key]) ) {
        if( $first ) {
            $query .= sprintf(" %s = '%s'", $key, $value);
            $first = FALSE;
        } else {
            $query .= sprintf(" AND %s = '%s'", $key, $value);
        }
    }
}
if( $first ) { die('no parameters given, query will error out.'); }
echo $query;
```

This is also terribly insecure for SQL injection, but I'm not going to implement parameterized queries here.